# MVVM DataTemplate Binding Issue

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

Perhaps this is a case of too much cold medicine, but I just can't seem to get this Binding correct.

Here is the (simplified) Window, with the a DataTemplate for each ViewModel type, which should just show an associated View:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DefaultViewViewModel">
            <local:DefaultView />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type other:AnotherViewModel">
            <other:AnotherView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is some of the MainViewModel (the actual ShowABCView methods are Command functions that do more than is shown here, for brevity):

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Stack<ViewModelBase> mContentViewStack;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        mContentViewStack = new Stack<ViewModelBase>();
        ShowDefaultView();
    }   

    public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
    {
        get { return mContentViewStack.Peek(); }
    }

    private ShowDefaultView()
    {
        DefaultViewViewModel viewModel = new DefaultViewViewModel();
        mContentViewStack.Push(viewModel);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
    }

    private ShowAnotherView()
    {
        AnotherViewModel viewModel = new AnotherViewModel();
        mContentViewStack.Push(viewModel);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
    }
}
```

And the MainWindow startup code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
}
```

When I run this, I get the error

> System.Windows.Data.Error: 40:
>   BindingExpression path error:
>   'Content' property not found on
>   'object' 'DefaultViewViewModel'

I know I'm missing something obvious here, but the Nyquil and friends betray me...

**EDIT - DefaultViewViewModel and DefaultView **

DefaultViewViewModel:

```
// ViewModelBase is basically just a wrapper for INotifyPropertyChanged,
// plus some other common-to-my-project properties 
// (NOT INCLUDING A Content PROPERTY)
class DefaultViewViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public DefaultViewViewModel() : base()
   {
   }
}
```

DefaultView:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <TextBlock Text="Some Hard Coded Text Formatted To My Liking" />
</UserControl>
```

Comment: can you show us the DefaultViewViewModel class?

Comment: I can, but you won't get much out of it... :)

Comment: The error could actually be in DefaultView, the error relates to something that binds to a property on DeafultViewViewModel, which looking at your code should be DefaultView.

Comment: What (if any) error message do you get if you remove the path from your binding entirely?

Comment: Does the content control display any text (such as a type name)?

Comment: It shows (as expected) the MainViewModel type name.  If I create a DataTemplate for that ViewModel with a simple TextBlock, it displays that DataTemplate (again, as expected).

Comment: Then I have to say it's not just the nyquil - that *should* be working. It's not like you're even specifying a Content property in the path. Generally I would use a ContentPresenter instead of a ContentControl, but that shouldn't make any difference and I'm not at a computer to test!

Comment: I usually use ContentPresenter also - I've been flipping back and forth on the hopes of something magical happening when I did... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer upstream from where I was looking.  There was an incorrect binding (used regular Binding without RelativeSource of the TemplatedParent) in the base View control that all of our Views use.

No more Nyquil for me...

Answer (score 1):

Well you haven't shown the code for the DefaultViewViewModel yet
but my guess is you defined "Content" as a field and not as a property.

to make sure that it will fix it, go ahead and overkill it by making Content a dependency property
hope that helps